# Ruby dowload file by content-disposition file attachment

Tags: ruby, linux, wget

**I'm using pure ruby not a rails framework**

I want to download the CSV file from a website `https://gis.cdc.gov/GRASP/Fluview/PedFluDeath.html` in some automate way. We don't have any proper link of that file, therefore, I have noticed all the https requests & try it at my side. I'm getting the following in response-header

```
{"cache-control"=>["no-cache"], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], "content-type"=>["application/octet-stream"], "expires"=>["-1"], "x-filename"=>["FluViewPhase4Data.zip"], "content-disposition"=>["attachment; filename=FluViewPhase4Data.zip"], "access-control-allow-origin"=>["*"], "access-control-allow-headers"=>["Content-Type"], "date"=>["Thu, 16 Apr 2020 08:35:21 GMT"], "content-length"=>["1689"], "strict-transport-security"=>["max-age=31536000"], "set-cookie"=>["TS01fffff8=015d0abe8741ca45a0240eb541c02a4c078ea85318c53937a00facbe48236a11e0a65133fa8c4d1dbe73e4451e594f198dcc4760a5; Path=/; Domain=.gis.cdc.gov"]}
```

Now I'm stuck how I can download that file. Is there any way that I can download file using above header response. Like we can use curl, wget etc but from the above esponse I'm unable to figure out.

So any answer to solve that problem will be appreciated!

Comment: you should look at the POST payload and try making a POST request to their endpoint and store the response to a file. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here though

Answer (score 0):

There are many data options on the URL you've provided which is a front end interface 
with many options on data you might be looking for. You may be able to automate this using the [ruby mechanize gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/master/EXAMPLES.rdoc)

But you probably will have a lot better luck looking at the [CDC's API's](https://open.cdc.gov/apis.html) and [open repos on Github](https://github.com/CDCgov)